# SignalR 2.0.2 and Owin 2.0.0 dependency conflict

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr, owin

I'm trying to get SignalR working in an MVC5 project with individual accounts.

The MVC project has by default Owin 2.0.0 and all of the Owin.* components are also 2.0.0.

So I used NuGet to get all the SignalR packages, it automatically resolved dependancies and downloaded v 2.0.2.

The project throws an error on startup with the following message:

> Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral,     PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35'

I also tried upgrading Owin to 2.1.0 but that didn't help either.

Has anyone faced the same problem and what was the solution?

Answer (score 49, accepted):

You can update this references to the lastest version I found (now is 2.1.0):

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin -Version 2.1.0
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security -Version 2.1.0
```

And make sure your Web.config have these binding redirects for version 2.1.0:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Or you can update this references to version 2.0.1:

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin -Version 2.0.1
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security -Version 2.0.1
```

And make sure your Web.config have these binding redirects for version 2.0.1:

```
<configuration>
  <runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
      <dependentAssembly>
        <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
        <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.1.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
      </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
  </runtime>
</configuration>
```

Answer (score 3):

Perhaps you need a binding redirect in your .config

```
<configuration>
<runtime>
    <assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
        <dependentAssembly>
            <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
            <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.2.0" newVersion="2.0.2.0" />
        </dependentAssembly>
    </assemblyBinding>
</runtime>
</configuration>
```

Comment: The problem was that the version 2.0.2.0 of Owin and Owin.Security could not be added for some reason, the PM wouldn't allow that. 
However I was able to get the solution to run by upgrading both the Owin and Owin.Security to 2.1.0.0.

Comment: Didn't work for me, but the exception message changed: Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

Answer (score 1):

In my case when I hosted my WCF service that has SignalR functionality in IIS and when I go to my IIS manager and to my application where I hosted my service right click `svc` file and click `Browse`, I was getting this error. So I did the following

In my Visual Studio, `Tools -> Library Package Manager -> Package Manager Console`

I made sure I selected my Website project that hosted my WCF service and gave below two commands one after another

```
uninstall-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR

install-package Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR
```

After this I just re-build my solution. Went to IIS manager and to my application where I hosted my service right click `svc` file and click `Browse`, I was able to see my service running in IE.

Comment: Worked for me, although not using WCF. Puzzled why you install and then uninstall.  I assumed it was a typo but realised it wasn't there to begin within.