# SignalR 2.0 error: Could not load file or assembly Microsoft.Owin.Security

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, signalr

I'm following this tutorial step by step

http://www.asp.net/signalr/overview/signalr-20/getting-started-with-signalr-20/tutorial-signalr-20-self-host

And I'm getting an exception on the line marked below

```
        string url = "http://localhost:8080";
        using (WebApp.Start(url)) //<------ error on this line
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Server running on {0}", url);
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
```

Error message:

Could not load file or assembly 'Microsoft.Owin.Security, Version=2.0.1.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)

More info:

In my project solution, the reference is pointing to the dll in the packages folder from NuGet

This has been added in my App.config file by NuGet

```
<assemblyBinding xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
</assemblyBinding>
```

In the packages folder, `packages\Microsoft.Owin.Security.2.0.0\lib\net45`, the file version of Microsoft.Owin.Security.dll is 2.020911.395

Comment: possible duplicate of [SignalR 2.0.2 and Owin 2.0.0 dependancy conflict](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439756/signalr-2-0-2-and-owin-2-0-0-dependancy-conflict)

Answer (score 64, accepted):

Ok I've solved it.

I had to upgrade my Microsoft.Owin.Security package to 2.1.0 with this command

```
Install-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security -Version 2.1.0
```

And modify the bindings in my App.config like this

```
<assemblyIdentity name="Microsoft.Owin.Security" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" culture="neutral" />
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.0.0" newVersion="2.1.0.0" />
```

Comment: Just to add for those running into this problem -- I did this and still received the error. It wasn't until I deleted all files from the web server and  republished that the error went away. Simply republishing without deleting first did not resolve the problem.

Comment: @Dave Deleting all DLL's from the bin directory and re-compiling worked for me too.

Answer (score 23):

In my case, I had two projects:

- `MyProj.MvcWeb` (an MVC application that referenced `Microsoft.Owin.Security 3.0.0`)
- `MyProj.Data.Entities` (a class library that referenced `Microsoft.Owin.Security 2.1.0`; not sure how this happened)

Upgrading `Microsoft.Owin.Security` from `2.1.0` to `3.0.0` in the `MyProj.Data.Entities` project fixed the issue for me.

Answer (score 7):

I took your idea, thanks for the research you did, and I did it like this:

```
get-project PerfSurf | Update-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security
```

It's much more simpler, and this will update manifest itself.

Ignore this (`get-project PerfSurf`) part, as I use it because I have multiple test project and don't want to update them all

Comment: `Update-Package Microsoft.Owin.Security` worked like a charm, thank you!

Answer (score 4):

Simple,
Go to your web.config file. Change the "bindingRedirect" tag for Microsoft.Owin, Microsoft.Owin.Security.OAuth, Microsoft.Owin.Security.Cookies, Microsoft.Owin.Security to as follows:

```
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="1.0.0.0-2.0.0.0" newVersion="2.0.1.0" />
```

this could work.

Answer (score 0):

This assembly does not match what was requested that is why you get this error. check the Microsoft.Owin.Security version in the GAC. Also see [here](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/junfeng/archive/2004/03/25/95826.aspx)

Comment: I do not have Microsoft.Owin.Security in my GAC. It's only in the packages folder

Answer (score 0):

in my case, it turned out to be IIS express issue.  Once i changed debug to Local IIS, error was gone.

Answer (score 0):

Renaming app.config to web.config works for me. Or just make a copy of app.config and call it web.config

Answer (score 0):

In my case, I have this error in code first during "update database". I  put "Set a as startUp a Project" in project with migration.it helped me

Answer (score 0):

I fixed it by changing my Web.config configuration tag:

from this:

```
<configuration xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/.NetConfiguration/v2.0">
```

to this:

```
<configuration>
```

dont know why this works.