# "SignalR" Doesn't recognize hub

Tags: c#, asp.net, signalr

I added all SignalR component but I still have got some errors about dll recognition.

> The type or namespace name 'Hub' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

### I added following libraries on NuGet;

- Microsoft.ASpNet.SignalR
- Microsoft.ASpNet.SignalR.Client
- Microsoft.ASpNet.SignalR.Core
- Microsoft.ASpNet.SignalR.JS
- Microsoft.ASpNet.SignalR.OWin
- Microsoft.ASpNet.SignalR.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.Owin
- Microsoft.Owin.Host.SystemWeb
- Microsoft.Owin.Security

I think, I don't need most of them.

```
namespace GenelProject
{
    [HubName("gsChat")]
    public class ChatHub : Hub
```

Why Visual Studio doesn't recognize SignalR hub when I want to use it ?

Comment: What version of SignalR are you trying to install and what version of .NET are you using?

Please, [see this page to see How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: I installed the last version 2.2.0

Comment: whats your visual studio version ?

Comment: @Oli I use VS 2015

Answer (score 3):

You only need the `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR.Core` package. And make sure you have the namespace `Microsoft.AspNet.SignalR` imported with a `using` statement in your file.

Comment: I removed all packages and just added SignalR.Core then Rebuild is fine but when I run the application throw an exception as Microsoft.Owin.Security : 0x80131040

Comment: I solved 0x80131040 error following solution; http://stackoverflow.com/a/22061918/1327316

Answer (score 1):

please right click on your project and select `manage Nuget Packages` then in `Installed` tab find `Microsoft.ASPnet.signalR` press uninstall. then try installing it again.

Comment: I already removed all packages and reinstall but it couldn't solve my problem. Even so yes you may be right, I read somewhere in this forum, sometimes that way may be a solution.