# Can I tell bindingRedirect to always use the latest available version?

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net, asp.net-mvc, assembly-binding-redirect

Having an ASP.NET application there are *several* entries in the Web.Config file in this format:

```xml
<dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="WebGrease" publicKeyToken="31bf3856ad364e35" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-1.6.5135" newVersion="1.6.5135" />
</dependentAssembly>
```

These libraries come as NuGet packages.

Now every time I update my 20+ NuGet packages I do something like:

1. One click to update all packages.
2. Open the application in browser.
3. See errors like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21439756/signalr-2-0-2-and-owin-2-0-0-dependancy-conflict).
4. Open my Web.Config, find the binding redirect entry.
5. Lookup the assemblies latest version.
6. Modify my web.config.
7. Update those steps 2…6 for all other updated NuGet packages with binding redirects.

This is *very* annoying.

**My question:**

Is there a way to tell the [`bindingRedirect` entry](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx) to always use the latest version?

E.g. something like:

```xml
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-*" newVersion="*" />
```

(Using a wildcard to tell the latest version)

The closest I came accross is something like:

```xml
<bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-9.9.9.9" newVersion="1.6.5135" />
```

(Only specify the newest version once)

Comment: As a very good workaround on my live websites on the server, I've written a command line script to automatically adjust the binding redirects by parsing the version out of the acutal assemblies and modifiying the web.config file accordingly.

Comment: Wouldn't mind sharing that script would you? I'm running into the same thing.

Comment: @asawyer Its deeply hidden inside a large custom [CS Script](https://github.com/oleg-shilo/cs-script) build script. Basically open config file, read DLL versions from assemblies, replace strings in config, write config file back.

Comment: Ah I see. Shouldn't be terribly difficult to recreate then. Thanks!

Comment: Yes, you can. Please see my reply below.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Unfortunately, the answer to this is no. See the [bindingRedirect element on MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/eftw1fys(v=vs.110).aspx).

To quote:

> **oldVersion**: Required attribute.
>
> Specifies the version of the assembly that was originally requested. The format of an assembly version number is *major.minor.build.revision*. Valid values for each part of this version number are 0 to 65535.
>
> You can also specify a range of versions in the following format:
>   *n.n.n.n - n.n.n.n*
>
> **newVersion**: Required attribute.
>   Specifies the version of the assembly to use instead of the originally requested version in the format: *n.n.n.n*
>
> This value can specify an earlier version than oldVersion.